# .NET PCL exception while converting time from UTC to specified TimeZone

Tags: .net, datetime, timezone, portable-class-library

I am developing a project in Xamarin Studio using C#. Its a .net PCL project and my profile is 78. My problem is, i am unable to convert a DateTime from UTC to specified timezone. I am using below code to convert DateTime from UTC to specified local TimeZone.

```
   DateTime dateTime = (TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime (DateTime.SpecifyKind (DateTime.UtcNow, DateTimeKind.Utc), profile.TimeZone));
```

I am getting below exception

> The Kind property of the dateTime parameter is DateTimeKind.Utc, but
>   the sourceTimeZone parameter does not equal TimeZoneInfo.Utc.

In PCL `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` doesn't have a parameter for specifying the `TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone`. It has only 2 overloads with below parameters.

> ConvertTime(DateTime, TimeZoneInfo) &     ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset,
>   TimeZoneInfo)

TimeZoneInfo exist only to specify destination TimeZoneInfo.

Also it doesn't have `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc, TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc` Methods.

Please someone help me to fix this.

Comment: This is all entirely by design.  Timezone conversions requires an operating system with a database that keeps track of the timezone rules across the world.  Available on a desktop class machine, not available on limited devices like a phone.  Without the database, you can only know something about UTC and the timezone for which the device was configured.  You cannot use PCL if this is a requirement, using a commercial web service to make the conversion for you would be a workaround.

Comment: I use http://nodatime.org/ in my Xamarin applications.

Answer (score 5):

To add to Hans's comment:

> This is all entirely by design. Timezone conversions requires an operating system with a database that keeps track of the timezone rules across the world. Available on a desktop class machine, not available on limited devices like a phone. Without the database, you can only know something about UTC and the timezone for which the device was configured. You cannot use PCL if this is a requirement, using a commercial web service to make the conversion for you would be a workaround.

Have a look at [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/).  This is a Date/Time library for .NET which has its own time zone data so it doesn't have to rely on the OS.  It also supports PCLs.