# TimeZoneInfo in Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin, portable-class-library

I have a requirement to get the timezone info of the "Mountain Standard Time" from the portable class library.In the WPF application I got the same by the below code.

```
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time");
```

But in PCL, I cant see this functionality.Could any one please tell me how can I achieve the same in PCL?

Thanks in Advance.
Roshil

Comment: Do you always need to get the timezone info for MST or does it depend on where the device is?

Comment: I think this SO question is similar to what you are saying.  The answer here may also be helpful for you as a workaround. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176274/net-pcl-exception-while-converting-time-from-utc-to-specified-timezone

Comment: Timezone info requires a database that is regularly updated with changes.  A desktop machine has one, mobile devices do not.  So of course it isn't supported by PCL, it is not *portable*.  A desktop machine weighs at least 20 pounds :) A portable solution is contacting a web service that provides you with this info, lots of them around.

Comment: I need to get the timezoneinfo of MST only.

Comment: What particular TZ info are you looking for?  If you only care about a single TimeZone, can you hardcode the info?