# Unable to find a constructor to use for type System.TimeZoneInfo

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, portable-class-library

I have a PCL project where I'm trying to `Deserialize System.TimeZoneInfo` object and it gives this exception:

> Unable to find a constructor to use for type System.TimeZoneInfo. A
>   class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with
>   arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute.
>   Path 'Id', line 1, position 6.

```
"{\"Id\":\"Pacific Standard Time\",\"DisplayName\":\"(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)\",\"StandardName\":\"Pacific Standard Time\",\"DaylightName\":\"Pacific Daylight Time\",\"BaseUtcOffset\":\"-08:00:00\",\"SupportsDaylightSavingTime\":true}"
```

Creating own converter may not be possible as what you can do with `TimeZoneInfo` object in PCL library is very limited. Any suggestions how to get around this issue or any other way to access `TimeZoneInfo`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET PCL exception while converting time from UTC to specified TimeZone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176274/net-pcl-exception-while-converting-time-from-utc-to-specified-timezone)

Answer (score 0):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo(v=vs.110).aspx),

> You cannot instantiate a TimeZoneInfo object using the new keyword. Instead, you must call one of the static members of the TimeZoneInfo class.

Comment: The problem in PCL, not everything is available and only very few methods available...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question...

This class is serializable, but it implements the IDeserializationCallback interface.
Therefore, in order to deserialize you will need to subscribe to it's IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization method.

Answer (score 0):

The one solution I came across is use Noda Time and we can do the conversion in datetimeoffset as such.

```
private static DateTimeOffset GetDateTimeOffset(string timeZone, DateTimeOffset userTime)
    {            
        var provider = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZone];
        return Instant.FromDateTimeOffset(userTime).InZone(provider).ToDateTimeOffset();
    }
```