# TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById not available in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, timezone, portable-class-library

I check the API documentation of System.TimeZoneInfo and it says that there is a method called FindSystemTimeZoneById which takes single string argument.

But, when I try to implement that in my Xamarin project, it gives me an error: TimeZoneInfo doesn't contain definition for 'FindSystemTimeZoneById'.

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

Comment: Is this Android, iOS, or Forms (PCL)?

Comment: I am developing cross plat-form app. But, the code is in PCL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET PCL exception while converting time from UTC to specified TimeZone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176274/net-pcl-exception-while-converting-time-from-utc-to-specified-timezone)

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById/p/System.String/, I can see that, its in there in the System Library. Then Why am I not able to get it in Xamarin.

Comment: Those docs cover the entire .NET BCL.  Not every portion of the framework is available on every platform, and this is even more true when working with a PCL.

Answer (score 4):

Portable Class Libraries do not have access to system time zones via the `TimeZoneInfo` API, because system time zones are platform specific.  Windows time zones are very different than IANA time zones found on most platforms.  Read more in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

If you need to work with multiple time zones in a Xamarin application, your best bet is to use standard IANA time zones (aka "tzdb") with the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library, instead of using `TimeZoneInfo` at all.

Alternatively, you could not use PCL, and instead create individual platform-specialized libraries, using the time zones available from each platform.  You will probably find this difficult though, as not only are the APIs different, but the data is different as well.